# Best practice: Ruby/Rails Rspec regex testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Could you tell me how to test regex-code correctly?

I test my user-login attribute with following code:

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...
  validates_format_of :login, :with => /^[a-zA-z0-9_.]{3,18}$/
end

# user_spec.rb
describe User do
  before(:each) do 
    @user = Factory.build(:user)
    @user.save
  end

  subject { @user }
  it { should be_valid }

  it { should_not allow_value("b lah").for(:login) }
  it { should_not allow_value("bälah").for(:login) }
  it { should_not allow_value("b@lah").for(:login) }
  it { should_not allow_value("bülah").for(:login) }
  it { should_not allow_value("bßlah").for(:login) }
  it { should_not allow_value("b!lah").for(:login) }
  it { should_not allow_value("b%lah").for(:login) }
  it { should_not allow_value("b)lah").for(:login) }
  # ....
  # Shall I test here every special sign????
end
```

But it seems very redundant and not secure.... Is there a best practice? Thx!

Comment: Just curious, what's wrong with using these characters in a user's login? It seems that something like `ü` should be valid.

Comment: Yeah, that was only an example... But there are several signs that wouldnt be good in a username, like /, (blank), ', ",...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not really testing your model here, you're testing your regex.  It's not quite the same thing.  Also, you're testing the same aspect of your regex, that it only allows [a-zA-z0-9_.], again and again.  If you want to apply different tests, test different aspects of it, eg with "lo" (<3 chars) or "12345678901234567890" (>18 chars).

Also, if you wanted to dry it up you could do something like

```
invalid_logins = ["b lah","bälah","b@lah","bülah","bßlah","b!lah","b%lah","b)lah"]
invalid_logins.each do |s|
  it { should_not allow_value(s).for(:login) }
end
```

Comment: Yeah, but there are about thousends of different special signs... And I don't think its secure to whitelist such signs...?

Comment: Like Max said, after a certain point you're just testing that "[a-ZA-Z0-9_.]" does what it says it does, which it always will. Test it a few times if you're *really* paranoid and then call it good.

Comment: yeah, regexes themselves are very reliable.  When regexes produce unexpected results it's because the person writing them didn't understand the rules.  In this case you can rely that [a-ZA-Z0-9_.] is going to only allow those characters.  It's not going to suddenly let some new character through because it's unusual or something.

Comment: And, as an example of misusing regexes, we've all done it!  You had [a-zA-z0-9_.] which should have been [a-zA-Z0-9_.], and rspeicher had [a-ZA-Z0-9_.] which also should have been [a-zA-Z0-9_.].  I blindly repeated rspecher's mistake in my last comment.  All of these mistakes will produce unexpected results.